# The Edit modal doesn't show up

Tags: laravel

So basically I'm trying to make a plan list page with with the input Name, total price, total gems, and image input is manually key in but for plan category input do a dropdown which the dropdown data is from plan_category table. The 'add new plan' modal works but the edit modal only fades but no form was shown.

plan-list page

```
@extends('mainLayouts/contentLayoutMaster')

@section('title', 'Plan List')

@section('vendor-style')
  {{-- Page Css files --}}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset(mix('vendors/css/forms/select/select2.min.css')) }}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset(mix('vendors/css/tables/datatable/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css')) }}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset(mix('vendors/css/tables/datatable/responsive.bootstrap5.min.css')) }}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset(mix('vendors/css/tables/datatable/buttons.bootstrap5.min.css')) }}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset(mix('vendors/css/tables/datatable/rowGroup.bootstrap5.min.css')) }}">
@endsection

@section('page-style')
  {{-- Page Css files --}}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset(mix('css/base/plugins/forms/form-validation.css')) }}">
@endsection

@section('content')
<!-- plan list start -->
<section class="app-user-list">
  <!-- list and filter start -->
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-datatable table-responsive pt-0">
      <table class="table">
      <button class="dt-button add-new btn btn-primary float-end m-1" tabindex="0" 
      aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" type="button" 
      data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#addPlanModal">
      <span>Add New Plan</span>
      </button>
        <thead class="table-light">
          <tr>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>Plan Name</th>
            <th>Total Price</th>
            <th>Total Gems</th>
            <th>Image</th>
            <th>Plan Category</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          @foreach($plans as $plan)
          <tr>
            <td>{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
            <td>{{ $plan->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $plan->total_price }}</td>
            <td>{{ $plan->total_gems }}</td>
            <td>{{ $plan->image }}</td>
            <td>{{ optional($plan->planCategory)->id }}</td>

            <td>
                 <a href="javascript:;" class="btn" data-bs-target="#editPlan{{ $plan->id }}" data-bs-toggle="modal">
                 <i data-feather='edit' style="color: #7367F0; width:20; height:20;"></i>
                </a>
                <form method="POST" action="{{ route('plan.delete', ['id' => $plan->id]) }}" accept-charset="UTF-8" style="display:inline">
                    {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    <button href="javascript:;" class="btn" type="submit">
                      <i data-feather='trash-2' style="color: #EA5455; width:20; height:20;"></i>
                    </button>
                </form>
            </td>

          </tr>
          @endforeach
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal to add new plan starts-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="addPlanModal" tabindex="0" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered modal-edit-user">
            <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header mb-1">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Add New Plan</h1>
                        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                    <form action="{{ route('plan.store')}}" method="POST" class="row gy-1 pt-75">
                    {!! csrf_field() !!}
                    <div class="modal-body flex-grow-1">
                    <div class="mb-1">
                       <label class="form-label" for="basic-icon-default-fullname">Plan Name</label>
                       <input
                         type="text"
                         class="form-control dt-full-name"
                         id="name"
                         placeholder="Plan Name"
                         name="name"
                       />
                       <div class="mb-1">
                       <label class="form-label" for="basic-icon-default-fullname">Total Price</label>
                       <input
                         type="text"
                         class="form-control dt-full-name"
                         id="total_price"
                         placeholder="Total Price"
                         name="total_price"
                       />
                       <div class="mb-1">
                       <label class="form-label" for="basic-icon-default-fullname">Total Gems</label>
                       <input
                         type="text"
                         class="form-control dt-full-name"
                         id="total_gems"
                         placeholder="Total Gems"
                         name="total_gems"
                       />
                       <div class="mb-1">
                       <label class="form-label" for="basic-icon-default-fullname">Image</label>
                       <input
                         type="text"
                         class="form-control dt-full-name"
                         id="image"
                         placeholder=""
                         name="image"
                       />
                       <div class="mb-1">
                       <label class="form-label" for="plan_category_id">Plan Category</label>
                       <select class="form-select" id="plan_category_id" name="plan_category_id">
                        @foreach ($planCategories as $planCategory)
                          <option value="{{ $planCategory->id }}">{{ $planCategory->name }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                        </select>
                     </div>
                    <div class='text-center'>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary me-1 data-submit">Submit</button>
                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
        <!-- Modal to add new plan Ends-->
    @foreach($plans as $plan)
    <!-- Modal to edit plan Start -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="editPlan{{ $plan->id }}" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered modal-edit-user">
            <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header mb-1">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Edit Plan Information</h1>
                        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                    <form action="{{ route('plan.update', ['id' => $plan->id] )}}" method="POST" class="row gy-1 pt-75">
                    {!! csrf_field() !!}
                    <div class="col-12 col">
                       <div class="mb-1">
                       <label class="form-label" for="basic-icon-default-fullname">Plan Name</label>
                       <input
                         type="text"
                         class="form-control dt-full-name"
                         id="name"
                         placeholder="Plan Name"
                         name="name"
                       />
                       <div class="mb-1">
                       <label class="form-label" for="basic-icon-default-fullname">Total Price</label>
                       <input
                         type="text"
                         class="form-control dt-full-name"
                         id="total_price"
                         placeholder="Total Price"
                         name="total_price"
                       />
                       <div class="mb-1">
                       <label class="form-label" for="basic-icon-default-fullname">Total Gems</label>
                       <input
                         type="text"
                         class="form-control dt-full-name"
                         id="total_gems"
                         placeholder="Total Gems"
                         name="total_gems"
                       />
                       <div class="mb-1">
                       <label class="form-label" for="basic-icon-default-fullname">Image</label>
                       <input
                         type="text"
                         class="form-control dt-full-name"
                         id="image"
                         placeholder=""
                         name="image"
                       />
                       <div class="mb-1">
                       <label class="form-label" for="plan_category_id">Plan Category</label>
                       <select class="form-select" id="plan_category_id" name="plan_category_id">
                        @foreach ($planCategories as $planCategory)
                          <option value="{{ $planCategory->id }}">{{ $planCategory->name }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                        </select>
                     </div>
                    <div class='text-center'>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary me-1 data-submit">Submit</button>
                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal to edit plan Ends -->
    @endforeach
  </div>
  <!-- list and filter end -->
</section>
<!-- plan list ends -->
@endsection

@section('vendor-script')
  {{-- Vendor js files --}}
  <script src="{{ asset(mix('vendors/js/forms/select/select2.full.min.js')) }}"></script>
  <script src="{{ asset(mix('vendors/js/tables/datatable/jquery.dataTables.min.js')) }}"></script>
  <script src="{{ asset(mix('vendors/js/tables/datatable/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js')) }}"></script>
  <script src="{{ asset(mix('vendors/js/tables/datatable/dataTables.responsive.min.js')) }}"></script>
  <script src="{{ asset(mix('vendors/js/tables/datatable/responsive.bootstrap5.js')) }}"></script>
  <script src="{{ asset(mix('vendors/js/tables/datatable/datatables.buttons.min.js')) }}"></script>
  <script src="{{ asset(mix('vendors/js/tables/datatable/jszip.min.js')) }}"></script>
  <script src="{{ asset(mix('vendors/js/tables/datatable/pdfmake.min.js')) }}"></script>
  <script src="{{ asset(mix('vendors/js/tables/datatable/vfs_fonts.js')) }}"></script>
  <script src="{{ asset(mix('vendors/js/tables/datatable/buttons.html5.min.js')) }}"></script>
  <script src="{{ asset(mix('vendors/js/tables/datatable/buttons.print.min.js')) }}"></script>
  <script src="{{ asset(mix('vendors/js/tables/datatable/dataTables.rowGroup.min.js')) }}"></script>
  <script src="{{ asset(mix('vendors/js/forms/validation/jquery.validate.min.js')) }}"></script>
  <script src="{{ asset(mix('vendors/js/forms/cleave/cleave.min.js')) }}"></script>
  <script src="{{ asset(mix('vendors/js/forms/cleave/addons/cleave-phone.us.js')) }}"></script>
@endsection

@section('page-script')
  {{-- Page js files --}}
  <script src="{{ asset(mix('js/scripts/pages/app-user-list.js')) }}"></script>
@endsection
```

plancontroller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\Plan;
use App\Models\PlanCategory;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PlanController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $plans = Plan::with('planCategory')->get();
        $planCategories = PlanCategory::all(); 
        return view('main.plan.plan-list')->with(['plans' => $plans, 'planCategories' => $planCategories]);
    }
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //Create new plan
        $plan = new Plan();
        $plan->name = $request->name;
        $plan->total_price = $request->total_price;
        $plan->total_gems = $request->total_gems;
        $plan->image = $request->image;
        $plan->plan_category_id = $request->plan_category_id;
        $plan->save();
        return redirect('plan')->with('flash_message', 'Plan Added!');  
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $plan = Plan::find($id);
        return view('main.plan.plan-list')->with('plan', $plan);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $plan = Plan::findOrFail($id);
        $plan->name = $request->name;
        $plan->total_price = $request->total_price;
        $plan->total_gems = $request->total_gems;
        $plan->image = $request->image;
        $plan->plan_category_id = $request->plan_category_id;
        $plan->save();
        return redirect('plan')->with('flash_message', 'Plan Info Updated!'); 
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        Plan::destroy($id);
        return redirect('plan')->with('flash_message', 'Plan deleted!');
    }
}
```

I tried to match the data-bs-target and tabindex, the problem could be caused by the controller but all credentials are matched, can anybody see what is going on?

Comment: try to remove the href in the a tag if your edit button to open modal.

Comment: same thing, the page only fades but no form popped up

Comment: Checking on the code you have, I can see that you are looping the modal. Try to remove the loop and change the id from `editPlan{{$plan->id}}` to `editPlan`. Check if this works. If it works, add a js function to populate the fields in the modal

Comment: dont forget to change the button `data-bs-target`

Comment: same thing happened, while removing foreach $plans plan causes some edit button not working at all

Comment: This problem is more on a bootstrap modal not opening rather than a laravel issue. Try to change the code in your question to reflect what you have done so far.

Comment: Were you able to open a modal in a plain html file?

Comment: @Mr.Kenneth "_The 'add new plan' modal works..._" The other modal seems to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind it was just a `</div>` missing thank you everyone

Answer (score 1):

Make a simple button named Edit Record in your foreach loop as followed:

```
 <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#YourModalName">
  Edit Record
</button>
```

Make a single modal at the bottom of body of your document. give it the same id as given in data-target of the Edit Record button above.

Then make a form with csrf token and all the labels and input fields (including a hidden input field for id of the record we will edit and save) inside your modal. Make sure to give ids to all input fields you want to populate.

Now I would recommend using jQuery for handling on-click event of the Edit Record button but you can do it with JavaScript as well. Just trigger a function on on-click event and fetch data for each field from the  where edit button was clicked upon (the nearest ).  Populate the form fields with that data keep id field hidden. On save handle the post request from controller and update the record and return back.

**If you use ajax to send post request then just make sure to reset the form inside the function you trigger on-click of Edit Record button for some other row and also to close modal on successful post request made using ajax.**